# Use JProfiler8 to profile camel routes

Tags: apache-camel, jprofiler

I'm using Apache Camel in my project. The routes definition looks like this:

```
  class RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            // populate the message queue with some messages
            from("direct:input").
             choice().
               when(body().isEqual("A")).
                 beanRef('aProcessorBean').
               otherwise().
                 beanRef('bProcessorBean').
              end().  
            to("direct:output");
        }
    };
```

This is very primitive example, which use only `FromDefinition`, `ChoiceDefinition`, `ProcessorDefinition` from [org.apache.camel.model](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/model/package-summary.html) package.

In real world route could be more complicated. I would like to know how I can measure time spent in each route. Basically I think I need to monitor all `XXXDefinition` classes from 
[org.apache.camel.model](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/model/package-summary.html) package. How to setup JProfiler to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the session settings and go to the "Filter settings" tab. Delete all default exclusive filters and add the top-level packages of your project as inclusive filters. Also add `org.apache.camel.model.` as an inclusive filter.